# Android application to browse the web using a physical keyboard

Tags: android, firefox

Recently I got an Android tablet, which I intend to use as a paper reader as well as a portable workstation. It can't substitute a desktop Linux but with a bluetooth keyboard and [terminal IDE](https://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/) there isn't much to complain.

While using the keyboard I find it un-ergonomic to have to constantly lift my hands to scroll the browser or zoom in (c.f. [Gorilla arm symdrome](http://www.wired.com/2010/10/gorilla-arm-multitouch/)), so I decided to look for [Vimperator](http://www.vimperator.org/), the extension for Firefox that makes it possible to surf the net without a mouse. However, it does not seem to be available on android...

Is there anything similar on android?